# How can I find listbox item index with item value?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, indexing

my

```
MessageBox.Show(listbox.Items[0].ToString());
```

is

```
"abber"
```

how can I find listbox item index 0 with "abber"?

Comment: Please clarify your requirement

Answer (score 20):

With `listbox.Items.IndexOf("abber")`

That is:

```
int curIndex = listbox.Items.IndexOf("abber");
if(curIndex >= 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listbox.Items[curIndex].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 int index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf("Specify string here");
```